# How to convert multiple embedded PNGs to JPEGs in Powerpoint file? - Filter PNGs by size

Tags: powershell, microsoft-powerpoint, conversion, png

This Powershell script "[How to convert multiple embedded PNGs to JPEGs in Powerpoint file](https://superuser.com/questions/1043668/how-to-convert-multiple-embedded-pngs-to-jpegs-in-powerpoint-file)?" works great, but: I also have lots of PNGs in the PPT, which are quite small and have transparent backgrounds. These get lost as jpg (no transparency anymore, but the background turns to black after conversion). The best solution for me would be: convert only pngs bigger than 100 kB. As I do not understand how to change the liked script, can anybody help me? Thanx in advance.

Remark: The effect is great. My test PPT got reduced by about 100 MB :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without testing it myself, I think that changing in the PowerShell
script the following line :

```
$zip.Entries | ? {$_.FullName -like 'ppt/media/*.png'} | % {
```

to this :

```
$zip.Entries | ? {$_.FullName -like 'ppt/media/*.png' -And $_.Length -gt 100000} | % {
```

will help to limit the loop to entries whose uncompressed size is
greater-than 100000 bytes.

Reference :
[ZipArchiveEntry Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchiveentry?view=net-8.0).